# How to reverse effects of jQuery replaceWith function on HTML select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page containing a "Country" HTML select tag and a "Region" select tag:

```
<body>
  <span>Country</span><br>
  <select name="country" id="id_country" onchange="changeRegion()">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
      <option value="US">United States</option>
      <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="CA">Canada</option>
      <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
      <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
      ...
  </select>

  <span>Region</span><br>
  <select name="region" id="id_region">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
      <option value="AL" class="US">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK" class="US">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ" class="US">Arizona</option>
      <option value="Avon" class="UK">Avon</option>
      <option value="Bedfordshire" class="UK">Bedfordshire</option>
      ... # other UK counties
      <option value="ON" class="CA">Ontario</option>
      <option value="QB" class="CA">Quebec</option>
      ... # other CA provinces
  </select><br>
</body>
```

I'm using the jQuery [chained plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) to change the contents of the region select tag based on the country the user selects:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.chained/0.9.9/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id_region").chained("#id_country");
</script>
```

The one wrinkle is that if the user selects a country other than the United States, the UK, or Canada, I would like to replace the region select tag with a region input text tag so that the user can enter the country-specific region they live in.  I think I know how to do this with the jQuery [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id_region").chained("#id_country");

    function changeRegion() {
      var country = document.getElementById("id_country");
      if (country.value !== 'US' && country.value !== 'UK' && country.value !== 'CA') {
          $('#id_region').replaceWith($('<input type="text" name="region" id="id_region_text" />'));
      }
    }
</script>
```

This seems to work fine.  The problem I'm having is figuring out how to reverse the effect of the replaceWith function if the user has selected either Mexico or Indonesia and then, for whatever reason, decides to select the US, UK, or CA.  In that event, I'd like to replace the text tag with the region select tag that contains the options for the country (US, UK, or CA) that they selected.  I tried creating a variable and then doing another replaceWith using that variable but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id_region").chained("#id_country");
    $select_region = '<select name="region" id=...</select>'   /* This didn't work */

    function changeRegion() {
      var country = document.getElementById("id_country");
      if (country.value !== 'US' && country.value !== 'UK' && country.value !== 'CA') {
          $('#id_region').replaceWith($('<input type="text" name="region" id="id_region_text" />'));
      } else {
          $('#id_region_select').replaceWith($select_region);   /* This didn't work */
      }
    }
</script>
```

How do I reverse the effects of this replaceWith function?  Also, is there a better way to do this?  If the solution does entail creating a $select_region variable, it will be difficult to maintain if I later decide to add more countries and their regions.  My JavaScript and jQuery knowledge is admittedly pretty weak so I'm not sure how to get this working.  The code is [here](http://codepen.io/rlfprog/pen/LkaRqX).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#id_region').replaceWith($('<input type="text" name="region" id="id_region_text" />'));
```

You changed the id from 'id_region' to 'id_region_text'. It would work the first time you replace it because there is a node with id 'id_region', but after that, $('#id_region_select') wont return anything because you replaced the id already. Use consistent id naming

Also, with each replaceWIth(), the events bound are lost, so you have to do `$("#id_region").chained("#id_country")` again

Comment: I tried following your directions (http://codepen.io/rlfprog/pen/LkaRqX) but now the results are worse.  When I select a country, I see all the regions, not just the ones for the chosen country.  And if I select MX or ID, I no longer get the text input tag.  How did I misunderstand you?  Thanks.

Comment: you were 99.99% there, i fixed that 0.01% for you http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOPBqV

Comment: you did var select_region = '<select name="region" id="id_region">.... I changed the starting of the quote to ` instead of  '

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I do like your "best solution" too not only because I can reuse the select_region var but also because it's DRYer.  I don't have to re-declare the entire select tag with all of it's options inside what I believe to be a "template string."  I wasn't aware of template strings until now.  I was working on a solution that clones the region select tag and then puts it back with a replaceWith but I was running into logic problems.  Your solution is much simpler and cleaner.  Thanks again.